# Initialize std::shared_ptr by copying a junk of data from a raw pointer

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, stl, smart-pointers

Basically what I was hoping to acheive:

```
int pBuf = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
std::shared_ptr<int> pPtr(pBuf, _ARRAYSIZE(pBuf));
```

The following syntax is invalid, is it even possible?
I'm required to use shared_ptr.

Comment: Since, by your own admission, the code does _not_ achieve your goal, we cannot magically divine what you want to do only by reading it. You will have to explain what you're trying to do....

Comment: What are you trying to do with `int pBuf = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};`?  Did you mean to have `int pBuf[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};`

Comment: @NathanOliver you're correct, my mistake

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, This is a general example where i want to copy a buffer into a shared_ptr without accessing any std::copy or memcpy functions

Comment: I have no idea what "copy a buffer into a shared_ptr" means, or why you don't want to use standard library features. Explain your goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean to create a copy of array `pBuf` and assign it to `std::shared_ptr` following code should work:

```
int pBuf[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
std::shared_ptr<int> pPtr( new int[_ARRAYSIZE(pBuf)], std::default_delete<int[]>() );
std::copy( pBuf, pBuf + _ARRAYSIZE(pBuf), pPtr.get() );
```